# Django Models: Accessing Parent Object Attribute Within a Related Object Using OneToOneField

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, one-to-one

I am trying to access the username attribute of a Django User object from a Profile object that is related by a OneToOneField.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.TextField(default=user.username, primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/profile')
    header = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='x')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

The intent of this is to be able to get a Profile object using a ReactJS frontend by passing the username provided at login back to a profile detail endpoint in a Django API, where the username is the primary key for the endpoint.

`path('<pk>/profile/', ShowProfilePageView.as_view(), name='show_profile_page'),`

I've tried many different things for the default argument passed to the Profile username attribute, but nothing is working so far. Is this even possible?

Addendum 1: ShowProfilePageView view

```
class ShowProfilePageView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    model = Profile
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the view `ShowProfilePageView` please?

Comment: @ruddra Sure, I have added it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply override the `lookup_field` in the View, like this:

```
class ShowProfilePageView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    model = Profile
    lookup_field='user__username'
    lookup_url_kwarg='username'
```

And update the url like this:

```
path('<str:username>/profile/', ShowProfilePageView.as_view(), name='show_profile_page')
```

Because through `lookup_field`, the view will look for the value in User model from Profile model. And `lookup_url_kwargs` is to map what value it should use from urls. More information can be found in [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/). **FYI** you should remove `username` field from Profile model, it should use `AutoField`(which is the default field for primary key in models).

Comment: This worked! I ended up having to rearrange the url path, but the lookup change was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To access the attribute of one-to-one field you can just do this:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(pk='profile_pk') # an object of profile
username = profile.user.username
```

To search Profile via username:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username='username'))
```

Thus, you don't need to define `username` field on `Profile` class